# Holt-Winters method in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

In R *forecast* package there is function `hw` with parameters beta and gamma.

What is the difference between not invoking the parameters vs assigning them `NULL`?

What would be difference between

1. `hw(Data, initial = "optimal", h=24, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL)`
2. `hw(Data, initial = "optimal", h=24, gamma=NULL)`

Answer (score 4):

In R, arguments to functions can have default values. Such arguments need not be specified explicitly while calling the function. You can find the default values for the arguments to a function by looking at its help page.

You can invoke the help for a function (say `f1`) by running the command `?f1`. Here is a line from the help page of `hw`:

```
hw(y, h=2*frequency(x), seasonal=c("additive","multiplicative"),
   damped=FALSE, level=c(80,95), fan=FALSE,
   initial=c("optimal","simple"), exponential=FALSE,
   alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL, phi=NULL,
   lambda=NULL, biasadj=FALSE, x=y, ...)
```

This shows that the default values for the `beta` and `gamma` arguments are NULL. Hence the two statements `hw(Data, initial = "optimal", h=24, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL)` and `hw(Data, initial = "optimal", h=24, gamma=NULL)` are identical.

Comment: Thanks this is what I thought to be. Actually a site showed one way as single exponential smoothing and other as double exponential smoothing!